# how to use nth-child in jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I have this site I'm working on where I have a table with inputfields in the 7th column and all the rows

My issue here are that I want the column 6 & 8 to respond to what I'm writing in the input field.

I even want to manipulate the row before and after the row I'm writing in the input field when I'm writing in the fields from "**Bronzealder**" to "**Kolonitiden**", and from "**Industritiden**" and onwards I want to manipulate the 2 rows before and after

I have a video of the site. But my code so far is only manipulating the 2 first body rows of my table regardless of what inputfield I'm using.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPKySob5f74

I am trying to achieve the same as this, but with some other ratio's:

https://forgeinfo.com/?l=tools&s=fairhandel

Are there anyone here who can help me with fulfilling my issue?

If I try editting

```
"$("input").keyup(function(){"
```

with this:

```
$("input:nth-child(1)").keyup(function(){
```

It wont work :(

```js
<script>
                $(function(){
                    $("input").keyup(function(){
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(6)").html(value / 2);
                        $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(8)").html("1:2");
                        $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6)").html(value);
                        $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(8)").html("1:1");
                        if (value == ''){
                            $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(6)").html("");
                            $("table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(8)").html("");
                            $("table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(8)").html("");
                            
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

```html
<table ID="tradeTable" class="tableTradeContent">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tidsalder</th>
                        <th>Billeder</th>
                        <th>Varer</th>
                        <th>Bedre lavere alternativ</th>
                        <th>Bedre højere alternativ</th>
                        <th>Resultat</th>
                        <th>Antal</th>
                        <th>Ratio</th>
                        <th>pris / 24 timer</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bronzealder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/BA/marmor.png"><img src="img/BA/tømmer.png"><img src="img/BA/farvestoffer.png"><img src="img/BA/sten.png"><img src="img/BA/vin.png"></td>
                        <td>Marmor, Tømmer, Farvestoffer, Sten, Vin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>400/400</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jernalder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/JA/stof.png"><img src="img/JA/ibenholt.png"><img src="img/JA/smykker.png"><img src="img/JA/jern.png"><img src="img/JA/kalksten.png"></td>
                        <td>Stof, Ibenholt, Smykker, Jern, Kalksten</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>800/800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tidlig Middelalder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/TM/kobber.png"><img src="img/TM/guld.png"><img src="img/TM/granit.png"><img src="img/TM/honning.png"><img src="img/TM/alabast.png"></td>
                        <td>Kobber, Guld, Granit, Honning, Alabast</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1600/1600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Højmiddelalder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/HM/teglsten.png"><img src="img/HM/glas.png"><img src="img/HM/tørret urt.png"><img src="img/HM/tov.png"><img src="img/HM/salt.png"></td>
                        <td>Teglsten, Glas, Tørret Urt, Tov, Salt</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>3200/3200</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Senmiddelalder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/SM/basalt.png"><img src="img/SM/messing.png"><img src="img/SM/krudt.png"><img src="img/SM/silke.png"><img src="img/SM/talkumpudder.png"></td>
                        <td>Basalt, Messing, Krudt, Silke, Talkumpudder</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>6400/6400</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kolonitiden</td>
                        <td><img src="img/KT/kaffe.png"><img src="img/KT/papir.png"><img src="img/KT/porcelæn.png"><img src="img/KT/tjære.png"><img src="img/KT/metaltråd.png"></td>
                        <td>Kaffe, Papir, Porcelæn, Tjære, Metaltråd</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>9600/9600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Industritiden</td>
                        <td><img src="img/IT/koks.png"><img src="img/IT/gødning.png"><img src="img/IT/gummi.png"><img src="img/IT/tekstiler.png"><img src="img/IT/hvalolie.png"></td>
                        <td>Koks, Gødning, Gummi, Tekstiler, Hvalolie</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>12800/12800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Den Progressive Æra</td>
                        <td><img src="img/DPÆ/asbest.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/sprængstoffer.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/maskindele.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/benzin.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/blik.png"></td>
                        <td>Asbest, Sprængstoffer, Maskindele, Benzin, Blik</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>16000/16000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Moderne Æra</td>
                        <td><img src="img/MÆ/færdigretter.png"><img src="img/MÆ/jernbeton.png"><img src="img/MÆ/smagsstoffer.png"><img src="img/MÆ/luksusmaterialer.png"><img src="img/MÆ/emballage.png"></td>
                        <td>Færdigretter, Jernbeton, Smagsstoffer, Luksusmaterialer, Emballage</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>19200/19200 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Den Postmoderne Tidsalder</td>
                        <td><img src="img/DPT/genomdata.png"><img src="img/DPT/industrifilter.png"><img src="img/DPT/genanvendelige ressourcer.png"><img src="img/DPT/halvledere.png"><img src="img/DPT/stål.png"></td>
                        <td>Genondata, Industrifilter, Genanvendelige Ressourcer, Halvledere, Stål</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>24000/24000 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nutiden</td>
                        <td><img src="img/NT/biometriske data.png"><img src="img/NT/elektromagneter.png"><img src="img/NT/gas.png"><img src="img/NT/plastik.png"><img src="img/NT/robotter.png"></td>
                        <td>Biometriske Data, Elektromagneter, Gas, Plastik, Robotter</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>28800/28800 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Morgendagen</td>
                        <td><img src="img/MD/ernæringsforskning.png"><img src="img/MD/papirbeton.png"><img src="img/MD/konserveringsmidler.png"><img src="img/MD/intelligente materialer.png"><img src="img/MD/gennemskinneligt beton.png"></td>
                        <td>Ernæringsforskning, Papirbeton, Konserveringsmidler, Intelligente Materialer, Gennemskinneligt Beton</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>33600/33600 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fremtiden</td>
                        <td><img src="img/FT/alger.png"><img src="img/FT/bio-geokemiske data.png"><img src="img/FT/nanopartikler.png"><img src="img/FT/renset vand.png"><img src="img/FT/superleder.png"></td>
                        <td>Alger, Bio-Kemiske Data, Nanopartikler, Renset Vand, Superledere</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>40000/40000 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Arktiske Fremtid</td>
                        <td><img src="img/AF/data om kunstig intelligens.png"><img src="img/AF/bioplastik.png"><img src="img/AF/nanotråd.png"><img src="img/AF/papirbatterier.png"><img src="img/AF/bio benzin.png"></td>
                        <td>Data om Kunstig Intelligens, Bioplastik, Nanotråd, Papirbatterier, Bio Benzin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>46800/46800 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Oceanisk Fremtid</td>
                        <td><img src="img/OF/kunstskæl.png"><img src="img/OF/biolys.png"><img src="img/OF/koraller.png"><img src="img/OF/perler.png"><img src="img/OF/plankton.png"></td>
                        <td>Kunstskæl, Biolys, Koraller, Perler, Plankton</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>51600/51600 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Virtuel Fremtid</td>
                        <td><img src="img/VF/kryptovaluta.png"><img src="img/VF/datakrystaller.png"><img src="img/VF/guldris.png"><img src="img/VF/nanitter.png"><img src="img/VF/te silke.png"></td>
                        <td>Kryptovaluta, Datakrystaller, Guldris, Nanitter, Te Silke</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input ID="input"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>64000/64000 (*)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: you are using nth child and binding it to every input - I don't see how you expect it to manipulate different rows when you are just targeting the same thing no matter what input you use.  If you want the current row then use `$(this).closest('tr')` and for the previous row, just add `.prev()` to that

Answer (score 1):

You can find the next and previous trs by using [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest), [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next), and [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev).
And then select the tds you want to manipulate with [find()](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://api.jquery.com/find)

```
   $("input").keyup(function(){
       var $currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var $nextTr = $currentTr.next();
       var $prevTr = $currentTr.prev();

       $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html('xxx');
       //....
   });
```